# Calculating posterior probability for double exponential distribution $\pi(\theta)=\frac1{2a}\exp\left(\frac{−|θ|}{a}\right)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1...X_n \sim N(\theta,1)$, and let $\theta$ have a double exponential distribution, $\pi(\theta)=\frac1{2a}\exp\left(\frac{−|θ|}{a}\right),\theta \in \Bbb R$,  for  some  known  constant $a >0$.

For a given constant $C$, I need to calculate $P_a(θ > C|x_1,...,x_n)$, but I need some help with getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood function is proportional to $e^{-\sum(x_i-\theta)^2/2}$.

So the posterior distribution is $f_{Post}(\theta) \sim \frac{1}{2a}e^{-\sum x_i^2/2 + \sum x_i \theta -\frac{\theta^2}{2}-\frac{|\theta|}{a}}$. This distribution can be split up into cases, $\theta>0$ and $\theta \leq 0$. Both times the resulting distribution is a normal distribution and you can complete the square to find out its mean and variance.

$\theta >0: f_{Post}(\theta) \sim N(\sum x_i +\frac{1}{a},1)$

$\theta \leq 0: f_{Post}(\theta) \sim N(\sum x_i -\frac{1}{a},1)$

Then to find $P(\theta>C|x_1,...,x_n)$, for $C>0$ you can find the integral from $C$ to $\infty$ of $f_{Post}(\theta)$.

For $C<0$, find the integral from $C$ to $0$ of $f_{Post}(\theta)$ and add $\int_0^{\infty}f_{Post}(\theta)d \theta$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I don't understand how you got $f_{Post}(\theta) \sim \frac{1}{2a}e^{-\sum x_i^2/2 + \sum x_i \theta -\frac{\theta^2}{2}-\frac{|\theta|}{2}}$. So far, I have worked it out myself up that point, and I arrived at $f_{Post}(\theta) \sim \frac{1}{2a}e^{-\sum x_i^2/2 + \sum x_i \theta -\frac{\theta^2}{2}-\frac{|\theta|}{a}}$

Comment: typo. You'll get $\pm 1/a$ in the mean instead of one half then

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response!

Comment: i got ur back..

Comment: Ok so now I am stuck at completing the square for 
$\frac{1}{2a}e^{-\sum x_i^2/2 + \sum x_i \theta -\frac{\theta^2}{2}-\frac{|\theta|}{a}}$

so far I have $\frac{1}{2a}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum x_i^2 -2\theta\left(\sum x_i - \frac{1}{a}\right) + \theta^2\right]}$ for $\theta > 0$ and $\frac{1}{2a}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum x_i^2 -2\theta\left(\sum x_i + \frac{1}{a}\right) + \theta^2\right]}$ for $\theta \leq 0$

but I don't know how to proceed further to get $N(\sum x_i \pm\frac{1}{a}, 1) \cdot N(?,?)$

Comment: you will get a $(\theta-(\sum x_i \pm \frac{1}{a}))^2$ term here, anything else is a constant of proportionality.

Comment: Ok so should I assume that the distribution of $f(x_1...x_n)$  in $f(\theta|x_1...x_n)f(x_1...x_n) = f(x_1...x_n;\theta)\pi(\theta)$ doesn't have to be normal?

Comment: that can be thought of as a constant of proportionality

Comment: I thought you have $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\theta)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2\theta\sum_{i=1}^nx_i+n\theta^2$. You seems to lose the factor $n$ in front of $\theta^2$.